# Rails Fog create a file based on a remote link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, fog, rackspace-cloud

I have Rails application and use `fog` gem to upload files to cloud storage (Rackspace). As of now I have been successfully uploading local files to cloud storage.

```
@service = Fog::Storage.new(options)
directory = @service.directories.new :key => 'test'
directory.files.create :key => path, :body => file, :content_type => content_type
```

I have a new requirement now. I want to be able to use remote link (public-url) and have it uploaded to cloud storage. Is there a way to achieve this without downloading it locally or loading the whole thing in memory?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
directory.files.create :key => path, :body => 'url-to-remote-file', :content_type => content_type
```

A stream-based approach would also be quite helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that it would take a file from an existing URL and store it to that location remotely? If so, we don't support that presently. I believe you would need to first download the file, then reupload it. Due to the way the cloud storage providers work, I'm not aware of a way to do this directly (though I haven't reviewed the latest API documents in quite some time).

Comment: Doing `File.new(URI.open(url)) ` and uploading works, but I am a little worried about loading the whole file in memory. Is there a stream-based solution?

Comment: Technically yes, though it gets complicated and API specific. Instead of URI.open, you could use something to download the file one chunk at a time (with a chunk-size set to whatever you might be comfortable with). Excon, the http library underlying fog, is capable of doing this for instance and giving you each chunk as the yielded object for a block. You would then need to upload each of these chunks to rackspace, and finally upload a manifest to "assemble". Docs here: https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/use-cases/additional-object-services-information/#creating-large-objects